# Как приостановить вызов события wheel, пока не произойдет прокрутка до блока?

Tags: javascript

изучаю Javascript и сейчас пытаюсь реализовать поблочную прокрутку страницы. Возникла следующая проблема: на данный момент у меня при прокрутке колесика мыши генерируется по нескольку событий и соответственно прокручивается сразу несколько блоков, в то время как необходимо, чтобы на на один блок приходилось только одно событие. Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать SetTimeout, но не совсем пока понятно, как. Еще была мысль вызывать событие "wheel" только когда закончилось событие "transitionend", но тоже ничего не получилось.

На данный момент код выглядит так:

```
'use strict';

var button,
  buttonTop,
  wrapper,
  scrollHeight;

window.addEventListener('load', function(){

wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
scrollHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

function addOnWheel(elem, handler) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        if ('onwheel' in document) {
            elem.addEventListener("wheel", handler);
        } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
            elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", handler);
        } else {
            elem.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", handler);
        }
    } else {
        text.attachEvent("onmousewheel", handler);
    }
}


addOnWheel(wrapper, function(e) {

    var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

    if (delta > 0) {
        scroll();
    }
    else {
        scrollTop();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});


function scroll(){
    if(scrollHeight <= (document.body.clientHeight*3)) {
        wrapper.style.transform = 'translateY(-' + scrollHeight + 'px)';
        scrollHeight = scrollHeight + document.body.clientHeight;
    }else if(scrollHeight > (document.body.clientHeight*3)) {
        return false;
    }
}

function scrollTop(){
    if(scrollHeight > (document.body.clientHeight)) {
        wrapper.style.transform = 'translateY(-' + (scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight * 2) + 'px)';
        scrollHeight =  scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight;
    } else if(scrollHeight < (document.body.clientHeight)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

Comment: на событие при определённом условии  взывайте preventDefault

Comment: Спасибо, уже получилось немного по-другому:

`if (delta > 0 && flag) {
            scroll();
            flag = false;
            setTimeout(function(){flag = true}, 1000);
        }
        else if(flag){
            scrollTop();
            flag = false;
            setTimeout(function(){flag = true}, 1000);
        }`

Answer (score 3):

Пример реализации через `transitionend`, без скроллбаров и лишних таймеров:

```js
const EVENTS_INTERVAL   = 500,    // интервал реакции на события
      SWIPE_SENSITIVITY = 0.33;   // чувствительность свайпов (0.33 == треть высоты элемента)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let elem = document.querySelector('.smooth-scroll'); 
  initSmoothScrollEl(elem); 
});

function initSmoothScrollEl(el) {
  el.blocksContainer = el.querySelector('.smooth-scroll_container'); 
  el.scrollPosY   = 0; 
  el.scrollPosInc = el.clientHeight; 
  el.touchStartY  = 0; 
  el.timeTransEnd = 0; 
  // выполняет прокрутку в зависимости от знака direction: >0 - вверх, <0 - вниз
  el.doScroll = function (direction) {
    if (!this.readyForScroll || !direction || Date.now() - this.timeTransEnd < EVENTS_INTERVAL)
      return; 
    direction = Math.sign(direction); 
    let newScrollPosY = this.scrollPosY + direction * this.scrollPosInc, 
        maxScrollPosY = this.blocksContainer.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight; 
    this.readyForScroll = !(newScrollPosY <= 0 && newScrollPosY >= -maxScrollPosY); 
    if (!this.readyForScroll) {
      this.scrollPosY = newScrollPosY; 
      this.blocksContainer.style.transform = `translateY(${newScrollPosY}px)`; 
    }
  }; 
  // реакция на колесико мыши 
  el.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.doScroll(e.wheelDelta || -e.deltaY); 
  }); 
  // реакция на свайпы
  el.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.touchStartY = e.changedTouches[0].screenY;
  }); 
  el.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    let touchEndY = e.changedTouches[0].screenY, 
        delta = touchEndY - this.touchStartY; 
    if (Math.abs(delta) > SWIPE_SENSITIVITY * this.clientHeight)
      this.doScroll(delta); 
  });
  // запоминаем время и ставим флаг готовности к прокрутке, когда переход завершится 
  el.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
    this.readyForScroll = true; 
    this.timeTransEnd   = Date.now();
  }); 
  el.readyForScroll = true; 
}
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body { background-color: #f7f7f7; }

.smooth-scroll { height: 100vh; overflow: hidden; }

.smooth-scroll_container {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 20px; 
  transform: translateY(0); 
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out; 
}

.smooth-scroll_block {
  width: calc(100vw - 40px); height: 70vh; 
  margin: 15vh auto; 
  font: 300 30vh sans-serif; 
  line-height: 70vh; text-align: center; 
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 #0004; 
  background-color: #fff; 
}
```

```html
<div class="smooth-scroll">
  <div class="smooth-scroll_container">
    <div class="smooth-scroll_block">1</div>
    <div class="smooth-scroll_block">2</div>
    <div class="smooth-scroll_block">3</div>
    <div class="smooth-scroll_block">4</div>
    <div class="smooth-scroll_block">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Реакцию на нажатия клавиш сможете легко добавить, если это будет нужно.