# Действие скроллинга вниз/вверх при малейшем движении колёсика мыши

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

При малейшем движении скроллинга он должен сразу же ПЛАВНО перескакивать на следующую страницу. Не должно быть долгого прокручивания: движение колёсика мыши вниз - и пользователь уже на следующем блоке и т.д., вверх - и снова сразу же плавный переход на следующий блок вверху.

```css
.block {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Text</div>
<div class="block">Text</div>
<div class="block">Text</div>
<div class="block">Text</div>
<div class="block">Text</div>
```

Comment: интересно ..а если куча текста который надо прочитать до конца а он БАЦ и перескочит ....

Comment: height: 100vh; - предполагается, что высота равна высоте содержимого экрана, поэтому здесь такой проблемы не стоит.

Comment: А если все же пользователь прокрутил колесико много раз - что делать? И как это должно работать для мобильных устройств?

Comment: Предлагаю двигаться поэтапно, а не отвечать вопросом на вопрос. На данный момент вопрос в том, как это реализовать, а не в том, как реализованный вариант подгонять под разные проблемные моменты.

Comment: @Alex вы не поняли меня , вы же читаете текст который находится в центре экрана ...т.е это комфортно ... и если текст в самом низу его будут скролить и будет скачёк

Comment: Я понял всё, но в моём варианте там не статья на 10 000 знаков, а описание товара от 3 до 5 абзацев по 1-2 предложения, что легко помещается на 1 страницу. На странице несколько блоков. Идея в том, чтобы пользователь при лёгкой прокрутке сразу же перескакивал на следующий блок на странице. Преимущество этого - сразу видно, какой товар перед тобой и не надо долго и много скроллить, если там 10 товаров на 1 странице.

Comment: Что бы вам помочь - надо полностью понять, как вы видите решение задачи. Как оно должно себя вести в разных ситуациях. Для этого и задаются вопросы.

Comment: У меня в задании не было запроса на адаптивность и разного рода проблемные ситуации. Просто обычное задание. Запроса на адаптивность нет. Для обычной десктопной версии. Я так понимаю, решения не будет, - будет только множество вопросов... :(

Comment: @Alex, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823731/Как-приостановить-вызов-события-wheel-пока-не-произойдет-прокрутка-до-блока/823967#823967

Comment: @Alex , Изобретать велосипед конечно интересно, но предложу готовое решение https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ru/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За одно прикосновение к колёсику мыши могут вылететь 5-12 событий onwheel. Вам надо в обработчике onwheel накапливать перемещения в пикселях, но ничего не делать, а ставить таймаут на 150 мс примерно, чтобы дождаться окончания серии событий. При поступлении нового события в течение таймаута, сбрасывать его и запускать новый, снова на 150 мс. Так вы избежите дёрганий.

По окончании таймаута надо делать прокрутку с помощью js. Время выполнения анимации можно рассчитать исходя из того, насколько сильно прокрутил колесико пользователь. Если суммарное смещение в пикселях больше одного экрана - умножить время анимации на количество экранов. Это уже зависит от того, как вы видите работу данного скрипта.

Пример кода (не совсем то, что надо, но близко), можно найти в [моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/622563/220220). Оттуда, по крайней мере, можно вытащить идею с обработкой onwheel.